# Zoom HTML Scroll BOX in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am trying to zoom a scroll box which is similar to the one here

http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_scroll_box.cfm

in a UIWebview.

Assume that I have set the above page as URL for my UIWebview. can I zoom inside the scrollbox ? I am able to zoom the entire webpage by setting the scalesPagesToFit = YES.
I tried setting the delegate of UIwebview subviews which are UIScrollViews to self and returning self.webview in  viewForZoomingInScrollView. But I am not able to achieve it.
Is it possible to zoom a scroll Box or a scroll area in HTML page in UIWebview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved zooming by handling the mouse move event in Javascript file and I am scaling the appropriate DIV. Now, the problem is that, I am not able to scroll the scaled content horizontally. My HTML page has position: fixed in CSS and I changed that to relative and tried giving overflow:auto and scroll. , overflow-x as scroll. But still the issue is not resolved